# Install application to client when the installer is located in web server in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, client-server

I need to install small application to client when the installer is located in web server in ASP.NET.
So how can I do this?
Please help me

thank you in advance.

Comment: Click Once Deployment? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d(v=vs.80).ASPX

Comment: Thank You Neil. I'm working on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ClickOnce Deployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d%28v=vs.80%29.ASPX) is commonly used to publish Windows-based applications to a Web server or network file share for simplified installation

> **What is a ClickOnce Application?**
>
> Simply stated, a ClickOnce
> application is any Windows Presentation Foundation, Windows Forms, or
> console application published using ClickOnce technology. You can
> publish a ClickOnce application in three different ways: from a Web
> page, from a network file share, or from media such as a CD-ROM. A
> ClickOnce application can be installed on an end user's computer and
> run locally even when the computer is offline, or it can be run in an
> online-only mode without permanently installing anything on the end
> user's computer.

Comment: Once again Thanks Neil.